# Display sku column in wishlist tab of customer view in magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

How to add column to display sku in wishlist tab of customer view in magento admin panel?

In **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Wishlist.php**, i have added below code under **protected function _prepareColumns()** to add SKU column in wishlist tab:

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('SKU'),
        'index' => 'sku',
        'width' => '100px'
    ));
```

After adding this code, SKU column is added but values (i.e. SKU of product) are not shown under this column.

Please help. How to display these values under SKU column.

Comment: You need to get the value of sku for each product. For example: `$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you plz tell me, where to add the code to get value of sku for each product in **wishlist.php**

Answer (score 0):

Extend to local code pool the following:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Wishlist.php
```

Create new grid item renderer at:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Grid/Renderer/Sku.php
```

And copy the copy the contents of the existing item renderer into that file:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Grid/Renderer/Item.php
```

Create new renderer adminhtml template:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/edit/tab/view/grid/sku.phtml
```

As in the existing item adminhtml renderer template, load the $product and fetch the SKU from it:

```
$product = $this->getProduct();

echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getSku())
```

Change the function `_construct` at the top of the file to call new renderer template for fetching SKU value:

```
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('customer/edit/tab/view/grid/sku.phtml');
    return $this;
```

Add SKU column to the function `_prepareColumns`:

```
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product SKU'),
        'index'     => 'sku',
        'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_grid_renderer_sku'
    ));
```

Resulting in:

[image: Adding SKU column to backend customer wishlist grid]